# What collection in PHP to count and order occurencies

Tags: php, arrays, collections

Using PHP 7.3/7.4 I'd like to use/create a key-value collection. I'd like to push many time the same key. Each time the value should increment (the first time the value is 1). And at the end, I need to get the key-value pairs ordered by values.

For example

```
$somecollection = ???
$somecollection->add('hello')
$somecollection->add('bye')
$somecollection->add('hello')
$somecollection->add('John')
$somecollection->add('bye')
$somecollection->add('hello')
```

should return

```
$ordered = $somecollection->ordered()
dump($ordered) --> ['hello' -> 3, 'bye' -> 2, 'john' ->1]
```

Does that allready exist?

Comment: Just use an associative array, what's the problem?

Comment: There's nothing built in that does this. It's 2 lines of code.

Comment: Do you want it ordered after each add?

Comment: Are you going to call ordered() once or can it be more than once? Is it a continuous stream of data going to come or is it just one time?

Comment: I'll call ordered only once, at the end. I'll use array_count_values as proposed

Comment: @thierryler Would you mind marking the answer as accepted, if you used it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Building this into a class will allow you to create counters as you need.  This has a private variable which stores the count for each time you call `inc()` (as it's an increment rather than `add()`).

The `ordered()` method first sorts the counters (using `arsort` to keep the keys in line)...

```
class Counter {
    private $counters = [];
    
    public function inc ( string $name ) : void {
        $this->counters[$name] = ($this->counters[$name] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
    
    public function ordered() : array {
        arsort($this->counters);
        return $this->counters;
    }
}
```

so

```
$counter = new Counter();
$counter->inc("first");
$counter->inc("a");
$counter->inc("2");
$counter->inc("a");

print_r($counter->ordered());
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [first] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: Good one, I would just change `inc()` to `add()` to match the question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the problem I have with add (as I mentioned in the answer) is that it isn't adding a number as such.  It would be up to OP to change it if they really want though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a native PHP function for this. See [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Just add a value by pushing it into a normal array:

```
$values = [];

$values[] = 'hello';
$values[] = 'bye';
$values[] = 'hello';
$values[] = 'John';
$values[] = 'hello';
$values[] = 'bye';

// Count the unique instances in the array
$totals = array_count_values($values);

// If you want to sort them
asort($totals);

// If you want to sort them reversed
arsort($totals);
```

Resulting `$totals` array will be:

```
Array
(
    [hello] => 3
    [bye] => 2
    [John] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this via:

```
function count_array_values($my_array, $match) 
{
    $count = 0; 
    foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) 
    { 
        if ($value == $match) 
        { 
            $count++; 
        } 
    }    
    return $count; 
} 
$array = ["hello","bye","hello","John","bye","hello"];
$output =[];

foreach($array as $a){
    $output[$a] = count_array_values($array, $a); 
}
arsort($output);
print_r($output);
```

You will get output like

```
Array ( [hello] => 3 [bye] => 2 [John] => 1 )
```

Comment: Reinventing the wheel with two loops, just `$output = array_count_values($array);`